# unable to get sys.argv[1] value

Tags: python

I am trying to execute a very simple script.
It only prints the first argument passed.

The code is

```
import sys
def check(argument):
  '''Open, read, and print a file.'''
  print argument

if __name__ == "__main__":
  check(sys.argv[1])
```

however when i execute from command line, i always get this error

```
C:\>sample.py myname

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\sample.py", line 7, in <module>
    check(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any help

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but you should always make sure to capture all possible errors. This includes checking that list indixes are not out of bounds, e.g. `try: arg = sys.argv[1] except IndexError: pass else: check(arg)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a Windows issue: http://bugs.python.org/issue7936

Comment: Why? It offers a potential solution, if you read through the thread on the bug report.

Answer (score 5):

Your script is fine, the way you execute it is wrong.

```
C:>sample.py myname
```

This uses windows file extension detecting to launch it with the python interpreter. Arguments might get lost in this way. Try executing it like this:

```
C:>python sample.py myname
```

Also, see [issue 7936](http://bugs.python.org/issue7936).

Comment: Thanks i followed the steps in issue 7936 to edit the registry values and it solved my problem