# what's the difference between "python scriptname.py" and just "scriptname.py"

Tags: python

what's the difference between "python scriptname.py" and just "scriptname.py"?

I meet the problem when using commands in Django, and this really confuse me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean when executing those statements on the command line?  The difference is "python scriptname.py" explicitly invokes the program named "python" in your path (in Linux, typing "which python" will tell you where the program lives), wheras "scriptname.py" is just executing that file, feeding it to the shell for interpreting.  If you give it to the shell, it should have something at the top defining what program to invoke when executed (in Linux, something like /usr/bin/python).  The shell then executes that program with the rest of your script, effectively doing the same thing as the first statement.

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478120/unable-to-get-sys-argv1-value) should also taken into account: